# Python fetch YQL result into MySQL

Tags: python, mysql, sql, json

I am new to everything mentioned. My target is fetching some financial data from YQL and insert into MySQL, which are done by making python call. Therefore, made following .py file:

```
import mysql.connector
import yahoo.yql

cnx = mysql.connector.connect(user='conn', password='abc123', database='yahoodata')
cursorA = cnx.cursor()
cursorB = cnx.cursor()

## Firstly, read all Symbol as an array in python

myquery = ("SELECT Symbol FROM yahoodata.nasdaq100list")
cursorA.execute(myquery)
myresult = cursorA.fetchall()

## Query YQL with each Symbol, literally loop 100 times

for i in myresult:
    yquery = 'select Symbol,Date,High,Low from yahoo.finance.historicaldata where symbol = "%s" and startDate = "2014-01-01" and endDate = "2014-12-31"' % i
    yresult = yahoo.yql.YQLQuery().execute(yquery)

    ## Insert Data from YQL fetch to MySQL

    insert  = "INSERT INTO daily_avg_2014(Symbol,Date,High,Low) VALUES (%(symbol)s, %(date)s, %(high)s, %(low)s)"
    cursorB.executemany(insert, yresult)

cursor.close()
cnx.close()
```

YQL successfully returned JSON formatted data. However, the INSERT will keep on saying "mysql.connector.errors.ProgrammingError: Not all parameters were used in the SQL statement"

When looking back actually what is being inserted to MySQL, I found the the format is not correct JSON since I place them into a string list / array

```
>>> print yresult
{u'query': {u'count': 252, u'lang': u'en-US', u'results': {u'quote': [{u'High': u'51.68', u'Date': u'2014-12-31', u'Symbol': u'YHOO', u'Low': u'50.459999'},
```

As what I understand, YQL seems did a great job returning result I need in JSON format, but my misuse of Python not getting it right and therefore cannot insert into MySQL. Any comment is appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: FYI also tried the json.loads

>>> json_str = json.loads(yresult)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/json/__init__.py", line 338, in loads
'    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/json/decoder.py", line 366, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
TypeError: expected string or buffer

Answer (score 0):

FYI.

Used pprint to successfully bypass that error

```
yresult = yahoo.yql.YQLQuery().execute(yquery)
jsoned_yresult = pprint.PrettyPrinter(indent=2).pformat(yresult['query']['results']['quote'])
```